# jQuery DataTable aaColomn not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatable

I use DataTable to display some of my data on my page, using ajax server side.

The js code is like below:

```js
$('#apply').DataTable({
    "bProcessing": true,
    "aoColumn": [
        null,
        {"mData": "booking_no"},
        null,
        {"mData": "dep_date"},
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null
    ],
    "aoColumnDefs": [
        {
            "aTargets": [0],
            "sClass": "details-control",
            "bSortable": false,
            "sDefaultContent": ""
        },
        {
            "aTargets": [3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9],
            "bVisible": false
        }
    ],
    "aaSorting": [[3, 'asc']],
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "<?php echo plugins_url('mybookings.php', __FILE__); ?>"
});
```

The ajaxsource mybooking.php returns values like this:

```html
{
 "sEcho": 0,
 "iTotalRecords": 4,
 "iTotalDisplayRecords": 4,
 "aaData": [{
  "aid": "1",
  "booking_no": "24****90",
  "source": "Booking",
  "dep_date": "2016\/**\/12",
  "ali_acc": "ty****om",
  "ali_name": "*\u53cb",
  "contact": "",
  "status": "\u5df2\u786e\u8ba4",
  "statement": "final",
  "remark": "\u5927\u5ba2\u6237"
 }, {
  "aid": "2",
  "booking_no": "93****70",
  "source": "Agoda",
  "dep_date": "2016\/**\/03",
  "ali_acc": "ty****om",
  "ali_name": "*\u53cb",
  "contact": "",
  "status": "\u5df2\u63d0\u4ea4",
  "statement": "",
  "remark": "test"
 }, {
  "aid": "3",
  "booking_no": "93****86",
  "source": "Agoda",
  "dep_date": "2016\/**\/04",
  "ali_acc": "ty****om",
  "ali_name": "*\u53cb",
  "contact": "",
  "status": "\u5df2\u63d0\u4ea4",
  "statement": "",
  "remark": ""
 }, {
  "aid": "4",
  "booking_no": "93****35",
  "source": "Agoda",
  "dep_date": "2016\/**\/30",
  "ali_acc": "ty****om",
  "ali_name": "*\u53cb",
  "contact": "",
  "status": "\u5df2\u63d0\u4ea4",
  "statement": "",
  "remark": ""
 }]
}
```

The page return a warning: "***DataTables warning (table id = 'apply'): Requested unknown parameter '1' from the data source for row 0***".

I tried and find out that the warning would be gone only if I change the format of aaData from json object into arrays.
That is to say, mybookings.php must return data like this:

```html
{
 "sEcho": 0,
 "iTotalRecords": 4,
 "iTotalDisplayRecords": 4,
 "aaData": [
  ["1", "24****90", "Booking", "2016\/**\/12", "ty****om", "*\u53cb", "", "\u5df2\u786e\u8ba4", "final", "\u5927\u5ba2\u6237"],
  ["2", "93****70", "Agoda", "2016\/**\/03", "ty****om", "*\u53cb", "", "\u5df2\u63d0\u4ea4", "", "test"],
  ["3", "93****86", "Agoda", "2016\/**\/04", "ty****om", "*\u53cb", "", "\u5df2\u63d0\u4ea4", "", ""],
  ["4", "93****35", "Agoda", "2016\/**\/30", "ty****om", "*\u53cb", "", "\u5df2\u63d0\u4ea4", "", ""]
 ]
}
```

I need to use json objects for some of my purpose,
But it seems like the aaColumn.mData parameter does not work.
Does anyone know the solution?

Comment: I guess something wrong here `"aTargets": [3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9],` , it should be `"aTargets": [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],` as 3rd column is not null..

Comment: Not that. I can totally remove the "aaColumnDef", or use "aaColumnDef" instead of "aaColumn", but all in vain. I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: try replace `aaColumn` to `column`, because you are using `DataTable` not `dataTable`

Comment: @user2352577L I tried to remove "aaColumn" and "aaColumnDefs", then add "columns":[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]," . still the same problem.

Comment: please follow the solution that i gave you, it must be work at the below method. I just finished my project with `DataTable`.

Comment: @user2352577L you might be right, I will try to find it out later. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `DataTable`not `dataTable`. Those are different.

**Javascript:**

```
$('#apply').DataTable({
    "processing": true,

    "columnDefs": [
        {
            "targets": [0],
            "className": "details-control",
            "orderable": false,
            "defaultContent": ""
        },
        {
            "targets": [3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9],
            "visible": false
        }
    ],
    "order": [[3, 'asc']],
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": "<?php echo plugins_url('mybookings.php', __FILE__); ?>"
});
```

**PHP:**

```
<?
$result = array();
$result_json = array();
foreach($db as $db_record)
{
  $result[] = $db_record->dataTable_col1;
  $result[] = $db_record->dataTable_col2;
  $result_json["data"][] = $result;
  $result = array();
}
echo json_encode($result_json);
?>
```

**EDIT**

Here are the links for reference for difference between `dataTable()` & `DataTable()`

https://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/22577/datatable-or-datatable
https://datatables.net/manual/api#Accessing-the-API

Comment: Thank you @user2352577L . Can I just change DataTable in to dataTable in my case? I tried your code but no server side data returns. I change DataTable into dataTable but still the same warnings.

Comment: @Tylor_E you cannot. can you provide your php code of server side for me. That helps me to fix your problem. Also you cannot change `DataTable` into `dataTable` ,because the `dataTable` or` DataTable` cannot read your data format. Also provide your ajax path.

Comment: `$aColumns=["aid","booking_no","source","dep_date","ali_acc","ali_name","contact","status","statement","remark"];
/* Indexed column (used for fast and accurate table cardinality) */
$sIndexColumn = $aColumns[0];

/* DB table to use */
$sTable = $table_name;
$sQuery1 = "
 SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ".str_replace(" , ", " ", implode(", ", $aColumns))."
 FROM   $sTable
 $sWhere
 $sOrder
 $sLimit
";
$sQuery2 = "
 SELECT $sIndexColumn
 FROM   $sTable
 WHERE  uid=".$user_id;`

Comment: `$aResultTotal = $wpdb->query( $sQuery2);
$iTotal = $aResultTotal;
$iFilteredTotal=$iTotal;
$output = array(
 "sEcho" =>intval($_GET['sEcho']),
 "iTotalRecords" => $iTotal,
 "iTotalDisplayRecords" => $iFilteredTotal,
 "aaData" => array()
);

$aRow=$wpdb->get_results( $sQuery1,ARRAY_A);
foreach ($aRow as $key => $value) {
 foreach ($value as $key1 => $value1) {
  $row[$key1]=$value1;
 }
 $output['aaData'][] = $row;
 $row="";
} 
echo json_encode( $output );`

Comment: sorry I don't know how to put such a long code in one comment. It may be not convenient to read. But you can see the result which the server side return on my main post.

Comment: why does not going to try the code that i provide? `aaData` cannot be use in `DataTable()`

Answer (score 0):

Finally I use dataTable 1.10.11 instead of 1.9.0, and jquery 1.12.0 instead of 1.7.1 to solve this problem. Both dataTable() and DataTable() are working.

In fact, this is not a perfect solution. Because newer version does not works good on jQuery makeEditable plugin (an old plugin I ever used, problems with add and remove functions). I am just a new programmer, I only have to load different version of plugins on different pages when needed.